e2e testing maven libs
Situation:

I provide several java libs and spring boot starter
I have a collection of spring test application that communicate with each other, enable me to test all uses cases

Goal

When a library / spring-boot-starter gets a new -SNAPSHOT release, i like to test it
A test would looks like:

the tekton build of an lib will trigger something after released a new -SNAPSHOT release
patch pom of test application to use latest -SNAPSHOT of each lib
compile test applications to docker container
run pods in kubernetes
start a cypress test
shut down all pods when the cypress test finished



Technology zoo
In my currently in use technology zoo are:

Kubernetes
Renovate
Argocd
Tekton
Bitbucket

How can the goal be achieved? Didt some one created a similar test setup?
